# Generate random BLOB in MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob

I have schema with tables contains BLOBs.
I need to do some performance testing of it, and I need to generate some dummy data.
Is there any way to make MySQL user defined function that will return BLOB of random values with given size (for example first I want to test schema for 256KB BLOBs, later I want to test schema for 2MB BLOBs).
Performance of this function is not very important. I can wait to generate test data for some time. (But for reasonable time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I happened to require something similar lately. I therefore created a UDF for generating random BLOBs. You can find it on my github.com account:

https://github.com/adrpar/mysql_udf_randomBlob

After compilation using cmake and following the post compilation procedures as described in the README file you can use the UDF like this:

```
SELECT randomBlob( sizeOfBLOBInBytes);
```

e.g. for a 128 byte BLOB:

```
SELECT randomBlob( 128 );
```

or combine it with your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I will look at it. What is license of your code? Can I use it in academic research?